# When to call DiscardView on RTV/DSV?

Tags: direct3d11

Is it a safe strategy to call `DiscardView` immediately before clearing the associated view? It seems that misusing this API could lead to bad things, so some explanation on how to effectively use this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DiscardView` is an optimization for tiled hardware renderering, so it's not strictly required.

In the standard Windows 8 Store, Windows phone 8, and universal Windows apps template, it's called right after `Present`

```
void DX::DeviceResources::Present() 
{
    // The first argument instructs DXGI to block until VSync, putting the application
    // to sleep until the next VSync. This ensures we don't waste any cycles rendering
    // frames that will never be displayed to the screen.
    HRESULT hr = m_swapChain->Present(1, 0);

    // Discard the contents of the render target.
    // This is a valid operation only when the existing contents will be entirely
    // overwritten. If dirty or scroll rects are used, this call should be removed.
    m_d3dContext->DiscardView(m_d3dRenderTargetView.Get());

    // Discard the contents of the depth stencil.
    m_d3dContext->DiscardView(m_d3dDepthStencilView.Get());

    // If the device was removed either by a disconnection or a driver upgrade, we 
    // must recreate all device resources.
    if (hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_REMOVED || hr == DXGI_ERROR_DEVICE_RESET)
    {
        HandleDeviceLost();
    }
    else
    {
        DX::ThrowIfFailed(hr);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the TBDR optimization is what I'm after. 


Since clearing the view seems to imply that "the contents will be overwritten," is it correct to call DiscardView immediately prior to clearing the view (even if, let's say, that view happens to be discarded+cleared multiple times per frame)? Or, is after Present the only valid place to discard?

Comment: In the loop cycle, doing it after ``Present`` or before ``Clear`` is equivalent.